# Chef kitchen.yml issue

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox

I am unable to run create virtual boxes in windows 10 using chef-kitchen, vagrant and virtual box. I have the latest version of all of them.  The system immediately crashes whenever I try to run kitchen.yml. I have even disabled hypervisor on windows based on some post that disabling hypervisor fixes the bug causing an issue with Windows 10 and virtual box. Please help me out.

```
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    driver:
      box: trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1
      box_url: trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
      customize:
        memory: 256

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[wbc_test::default]
    attributes:
```

Comment: please include the error message

Comment: I am not getting an error message. The system just shuts down. Is there a specific way to troubleshoot this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: also, please note I can see my VM on virtual box, but when I click on open, the system just restarts.

Comment: After searching for the logs, this is what I found: It got stuck at: default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

Comment: try to execute  `kitchen converge` with `--debug --log_level debug` and then recheck the logs. moreover, i will advise you to do that under linux subsystem (which is integrated into windows 10)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out that the base issue was that I was trying to run a nested VM. It worked once I enabled sharing my VM resources.

Comment: how did you figure out what was the problem? (and you never mentioned that your host operating system is a virtual-machine)

Comment: Yes, I was unaware that the host operating system could cause the issue. I was going through a VMWare document which mentioned that you need to enable Sharing resources to VM's needs to be enabled before starting a VM. It also mentioned that VMWare is not responsible for any malfunction caused by this. It seems like this is a VMWare specific issue.

Comment: According to me your Q&A is more on-topic on [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions). SO and SF are about software and system engineering respectively.